# How can I compile and run a C program using fexec in a bootstrap program?

Tags: c, bash, unix

I have a C program `system_math_bs.c` that writes a simple program called `math.c`, compiles, and runs it.

It works as it is right now, but it uses the function `system()` to compile and run math.c.

I need it to do the same thing, but using the system call `fexecve` instead of `system()`.

Here is `system_math_bs.c` for reference:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    printf("system_bootstrap pid:%d\n", getpid());
    char *program = 
            "#include <stdio.h>\n"
            "#include <stdlib.h>\n"
            "#include <unistd.h>\n"
            "int result;\n"
            "int main(int argc, char *argv[]){\n"
                    "printf(\"main_add pid: %d\\n\", getpid());\n"

                    "int a = 0;\n"
                    "int b = 0;\n"
                    "char* op;\n"
                    "op = argv[1];\n"   // this arg has to be +, -, *, or /
                    "a = atoi(argv[2]);\n"
                    "b = atoi(argv[3]);\n"

                    // Couldn't use op for the switch statement, it asked for an int.
                    // So the following if-else-if's make an int choice to replace op

                    "int choice = 0;\n"
                    "if(*op == '+')\n"
                            "choice = 1;\n"
                    "else if(*op == '-')\n"
                            "choice = 2;\n"
                    "else if(*op == '*')\n"
                            "choice = 3;\n"
                    "else if(*op == '/')\n"
                            "choice = 4;\n"
                
                    "switch(choice){\n"
                            "case 1:\n"
                                    "result = a + b;\n"
                                    "printf(\"%d + %d = %d \\n\", a, b, result);\n"
                                    "break;\n"
                            "case 2:\n"
                                    "result = a - b;\n"
                                    "printf(\"%d - %d = %d \\n\", a, b, result);\n"
                                    "break;\n"
                            "case 3:\n"
                                    "result = a * b;\n"
                                    "printf(\"%d * %d = %d \\n\", a, b, result);\n"
                                    "break;\n"
                            "case 4:\n"
                                    "result = a / b;\n"
                                    "printf(\"%d / %d = %d \\n\", a, b, result);\n"
                                    "break;\n"
                            "default:\n"
                                    "printf(\"Invalid choice.\\n\");\n"
                                    "break;\n"
                    "}\n"
            "return 0;\n"
            "}\n";
    
    
    int fd = creat("./math.c", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    printf("fd for math.c file:%d\n", fd);
    write(fd, program, strlen(program));



    // Must change the following statements to use the system call fexecve

    system("cc ./math.c -o math");
    system("./math + 10 40");
    
}
```

I have to change the last 2 lines to use the system call `fexecve` instead of the `system` function. So I have to compile math.c then run it using `fexecve`.

***I know that if I have 2 `fexecve` system calls, the second one won't get executed.***

*The work-around is to create a child process using `fork()`, give the `fexecve()` of the C compiler to the child and the `fexecve` of the math program to the parent.*

I tried the following.

```
    pid_t childpid = fork();
    if(childpid == 0){ //child process
        int cc = open("usr/bin/cc", O_RDONLY);
        char *argvC[] = {"/usr/bin/cc", NULL};
        char *environC[] = {NULL};
        fexecve(cc, argvC, environC);
    }
    if(childpid > 0){ //parent process
        wait(0);
        printf("executing the math program ...\n");
        char *newargv[] = {"./math", "+", "6", "1"};
        char *newenviron[] = {NULL};

        int res = fexecve(fd, newargv, newenviron);
        printf("%d\n", res);
    }
```

Output:

```
system_math_bs pid:2062182
fd for math.c file: 3
executing the math program ...
-1
```

How should I do the system call so that it works?

Comment: After re-reading my question, now I think that even if I correctly wrote the fexecve() for compiling and left the second one as "system(./math + 10 40)", the latter wouldn't get executed. Right?

Comment: `system("...argument...")` itself does a `fork` and then a `execve()` in the child created by fork, passing `"/bin/sh", "-c", "...argument..."` as arguments to that new command; and then in the original process a `wait()` to let the forked-off process -- replaced with `sh` by the `exec`-family call -- finish. The parts you're missing are the `fork()` and the `wait()`.

Comment: You're right. I edited my question, I tried adding the `fork()` and `wait(0)`. It's still not compiling `math.c` or running it

Comment: Right now I wouldn't expect your `open()` to work (unless you're running your code in the operating system's root directory) because the file path is missing the leading `/`. Have you checked whether the file descriptor returned by `open()` is actually a positive number?

Comment: Also, your fexecve needs a file descriptor on `math`, not `cc`, which you can only open successfully after `cc` is finished; your latter code doesn't appear to be opening the fd between those points.

Comment: Really, as a rule, it's not acceptable to leave out error handling code even during development/prototyping. How do you know what's going wrong if you don't check for errors and call `perror()` immediately after the initial failure? That means _every_ call needs to be checked and followed by a perror if it failed -- `creat()`, `write()`, `open()`, `fexecve()`, everything.